# Does azure force kill processes by itself? My nodeJS/Java processes/Jmeter are force killed

Tags: azure, performance-testing, kill

I am using windows azure for a performance test in about 8 nodes, each running a different application. Since its a performance test, we do have quite a bit of traffic generated.

The test was running just fine for a few hours. Then suddenly we realise a few of the applications like nodeJS, JMeter and even Java processes have been force-killed. Each at a different time.

We find nothing in logs that indicate a out of memory or any other error or application issue. And this happens pretty often, once every few hours. For example we had seen this issue with jmeter shut down once every 3-4 hours and then once it had happened after 10 hours or continuous run.

So we suspect azure is using root permissions to force-kill the above processes.

Did any of you notice this with your applictaions on azure and do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no, Azure does not kill your processes.  There is no such thing as 'root permissions' to kill specific processes.

Are you running an IaaS VM or a PaaS Web/Worker Role?  For PaaS, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx for where to start getting diagnostic data.  For IaaS, troubleshoot it like you would on-prem (DebugDiag, WinDBG, procmon, Application/System event logs, etc) since there is really nothing specific about Azure that would cause this behavior.